Static reference with a Context field will make an Activity to never be GC? Using shared preferences instead?
I have a static reference to an object that has a Context field into an activity.
This is activity is pretty much a container for a WebView and it's reachable with the use of intent-filter. In other words, links can be opened directly inside my app.
Using instance variables would be pretty much pointless since the Activity gets destroyed when no longer has focus so I am using static instances for a boolean that is works as an option chooser and an object (with a Context field) that needs to perform work
   static boolean autoTrain = false;
   static AutoTrain autoTrain = new AutoTrain(getApplicationContext(),string);

But Android Studio is warning me:

Do not place Android context classes in static fields (static
reference to AutoWalk2 which has field context pointing to Context);
this is a memory leak  Non-static inner classes have an implicit
reference to their outer class. If that outer class is for example a
Fragment or Activity, then this reference means that the long-running
handler/loader/task will hold a reference to the activity which
prevents it from getting garbage collected.  Similarly, direct field
references to activities and fragments from these longer running
instances can cause leaks.  ViewModel classes should never point to
Views or non-application Contexts.

Usually I would have done this work inside a service but I would rather avoid using a Service and do everything inside my browser activity.
Could I use SharedPreferences to save both the boolean and the AutoTrain instead of using static references?
SharedPreferences allows only primitives as far as I know but I think with google-gson one can save also objects.
Although I am not sure how this will impact efficiency (speed in particular).

you still need context with shared preferences so you are not really fixing anything by doing that

@tyczj yes but it wouldn't be a static reference, so why not?

oh I thought you were saying you would have a static shared preference reference

Your AutoTrain class presumably is declared to take a Context. Change that to take an Application to avoid this warning.
You might also consider switching from raw static fields to using dependency inversion frameworks (Dagger/Hilt, or things like Koin if someday you move to Kotlin).

SharedPreferences allows only primitives as far as I know but I think with google-gson one can save also objects

Not if AutoTrain holds a reference to a Context or other data that cannot be represented in JSON.

Using Application instead of Context would solve the memory leak?
I see, then SharedPreferences would be of no help in this case scenario.

@zaxunobi: An Application is a singleton Context. It is pre-leaked; you cannot leak it further.

Since getApplication() and getApplicationContext() are both singleton Context, then what's the difference? I suppose the devs advice to use only getApplicationContext() instead of getApplication().

@zaxunobi: They should return the same object. I never understood why they have both. IIRC, it is an oddity from API Level 1 that they have maintained for over a decade for backwards compatibility.

I see. Then why have you advised me to use Application instead of Context? Just to "remove" the warning? Or for the benefit of avoiding further leaks?

@zaxunobi: "Just to "remove" the warning?" -- yes. You already are using the Application singleton. However, your method signature allows you to potentially use something else, which is what is triggering the complaint.
